# Do i need a hashtag in Javascript to pass as a Div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How do i insert this php DivSomething into Javascript? Since Javascript needs a hashtag to recognize that as a div. Is there a way to tell JS that this is a Div or there's other better way to do it? Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
<script>
/*How do i insert a var DivSomething into JS with a hashtag */
/* DivSomething is php dynamic. It returns a Div. It can be #Div1, #Div2, #Div3... */

var DivSomething = '<?php echo $Highlight; ?>'

$(function() {
  $('#MouseHere').hover(function() {   
    $('#' + DivSomething).css('background-color', '#ffffff');

}, function() {
 // on mouseout, reset the background colour
   $('#' + DivSomething).css('background-color', '');

</script>
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? Have you looked at resulting HTML? What is actual value of `DivSomething` in rendered HTML?

Comment: What are you talking about? JavaScript doesn't have anything to do with hashtags. JQuery does though, you use hashtags to find elements with the specified ID's on the page. Those elements have to be rendered first (with PHP in your case) on the side of the server. You will never find `<?something ?>` in JavaScript since it's a server instruction

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Why not this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#MouseHere').hover(function() {   
    $('#<?php echo $Highlight; ?>').css('background-color', '#ffffff');

}, function() {
 // on mouseout, reset the background colour
   $('#<?php echo $Highlight; ?>').css('background-color', '');
```

Comment: It may or may not produce any useful result depending on what php outputs to the page... You probably should specify what are expected values of php variables are.

Comment: @Alexi Levenkov. It doesnt work unfortunately. Is that because of String problem? Assuming my php $Highlight produces Div1 which i tested with echo. This is exactly the Div name as recognized in HTML and CSS. It works if i pass that independent of php as  $('#Div1').css('background-color', '#ffffff'); but not when i try to pass that as per your suggestion. Judging from such a wisdomless question, one can tell i'm not coding literated. Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: @Mike I assumed from your question that the hash was included in your PHP string - if it's not, you need to add it to identify the correct div by it's `id` attribute - answer updated accordingly.

Comment: i found the answer. i did this:  $('#<?php echo $Highlight; ?>').css('background-color', ''); Adding one hashtag in it and it works! Thanks everyone. Especially @scrowler

Answer (score 0):

hashtag doesn't mean div it's selector by id

you can do this way

### HTML render

```
<div id="yourdiv" class="<?php echo(/* should highlight this? */true)? 'highlight':''; ?>">
  ...
</div>
```

here you calculate should the `#yourdiv` be highlight

### javascript

```
$(function() {
  $('#MouseHere').mouseover(function() {   
    $('.highlight').css('background-color', '#fff');
  })
  .mouseout(function(){
    $('.highlight').css('background-color', 'transparent');
  })
});
```

completely separate javascript and PHP render logic.